# How can we efficiently check if a string is hexadecimal in Python

Tags: python, python-internals

I need to check if a string is hexadecimal. I learnt 2 approaches -

1.) Looping over each character

```
all(c in string.hexdigits for c in s) # Straight forward with no optimizations
```

2.) Use [int](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/int.html)() function to check for an error

```
try:
    int(s, 16)
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False
```

In the 1st case I know the complexity is O(n). But what about the 2nd one? What is the time complexity there?

Comment: How large is your data and how often do you expect non-hex digits? Throwing an exception takes some amount of time as well so if you expect to throw a lot of them it won't be very efficient.

Comment: Strings are not really big. At max 60 characters. Checks are required only once in a flow. But the flow needs to be real swift. This in turn demands us to optimize everything possible.

Comment: In terms of complexity it should be the same O(n), where n is the numbers of characters in `s`. Note that is probably faster to do `set(s) < set(string.hexdigits)`,  what I mean is faster to check a set than a string for containment.

Comment: as for me `int()` whould need one `for`-loop to convert it - so it is O(n). But you could also use `time` to check real time for few example and then see which one can be faster. Probably both will be very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int(s, 16)` will still have complexity O(n), where `n == len(s)`, but the two aren't directly comparable. `int` will be iterating over the data at a lower level than `all`, which is faster, but `int` also does more work (it actually has to compute the integer value of `s`).

So which is faster? You have to profile both.

```
In [1]: s = "783c"

In [2]: import string

In [3]: %timeit all(c in string.hexdigits for c in s)
800 ns ± 3.23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: try:
   ...:   int(s, 16)
   ...: except ValueError:
   ...:   pass
   ...:
223 ns ± 1.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Looks like internal iteration wins. I tested on an 9-digit string as well, and `int` was still about 4x faster.

But what about *invalid* strings?

```
In [8]: s = 'g'

In [9]: %%timeit
   ...: try:
   ...:   int(s, 16)
   ...: except ValueError:
   ...:   pass
   ...:
1.09 µs ± 2.62 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit all(c in string.hexdigits for c in s)
580 ns ± 6.55 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Now, we're basically testing the benefit of short-circuiting versus the cost of catching an exception. What happens if the error occurs later in the string?

```
In [11]: s = "738ab89ffg"

In [12]: %timeit all(c in string.hexdigits for c in s)
1.59 µs ± 19.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: try:
    ...:   int(s, 16)
    ...: except ValueError:
    ...:   pass
    ...:
1.25 µs ± 19.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Now we're seeing the benefit to internal iteration again.

Comment: Out of interest, can you add a version that uses `str.translate()` to the profile (`remove_hex = str.maketrans({c: None for c in string.hexdigits})` and `s.translate(remove_hex) == ''` as the check)?

Comment: Awesome. I could have tried this. Thanks. Can we get to see the implementation of this function somewhere?

Comment: ...or not, I just did it myself. `str.translate()` is orders of magnitude slower. Interesting.

Comment: @Tomalak It's slower than `int`, but much closer to it than `all(...)`. However, it's much more verbose than `int` for no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a string is representing a valid hex number or not means, that you need a bool value. Here you may also use python sets using the issubset() function (Python 2.4 and higher).
A run with 10,000 cyles delievers same execution times. Also with longer strings and non hex values.
I prefer using sets as you directly get a bool value:

```
import time

cycles = 100000

hex_set = set('abcdefABCDEF0123456789')
s = 'FFbcdf7340958390230203400348dfsfAF992394787834DE'

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(cycles):
    s_set = set(s)
    ishex = s_set.issubset(hex_set)

end_time = time.time()
mean_time = (end_time - start_time)/cycles
print('Execution time:', mean_time, 'seconds')

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(cycles):
    try:
        ishex = bool(int(s, 16))
    except ValueError:
        ishex = False
        
end_time = time.time()
mean_time = (end_time - start_time)/cycles
print('Execution time:', mean_time, 'seconds')

Execution time: 2.4258804321289062e-06 seconds
Execution time: 2.663140296936035e-06 seconds
```